# Rails app w/ Heroku - Home page doesn't exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, deployment

My app runs perfectly on my localhost, but when I push it to Heroku, my home page gives me a message that says 'The page you were looking for doesn't exist.' Other pages (not all, but most) within the app display correctly on Heroku. Here is the output from running `heroku run cat config/routes.rb`:

```
Running `cat config/routes.rb` attached to terminal... up, run.8019
SampleApp::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :users
  resources :sessions,      only: [:new, :create, :destroy]
  resources :relationships, only: [:create, :destroy]
  resources :teams
  resources :players
  resources :matchups

  root 'static_pages#home'
  match '/signup',  to: 'users#new',            via: 'get'
  match '/signin',  to: 'sessions#new',         via: 'get'
  match '/signout', to: 'sessions#destroy',     via: 'delete'
  match '/help',    to: 'static_pages#help',    via: 'get'
  match '/about',   to: 'static_pages#about',   via: 'get'
  match '/contact', to: 'static_pages#contact', via: 'get'
  match '/updatepts', to: 'static_pages#updatepts', via: 'get'
  match '/findMatchup', to: 'static_pages#findMatchup', via: 'get'
```

The other page that notably does not display is `matchups/:id`. Any ideas as to why this is displaying with no problem locally, but will not work on Heroku? Thanks!

Edit: I am running Rails 4 w/ Ruby 2.

Comment: What does your `StaticPagesController` look like?

Comment: @farleyknight, I've added the controller, it has a bunch of the apps logic in it, but it works perfectly on the local server.

Comment: are you sure that you have deployed all the resources under static_pages directory? Also you can try modifying root :to => 'static_pages#home' and move it to the extreme end of the routes file

Comment: @raghu I think they are all deployed, how can I check this? I'll try moving root to, but why would that matter? Thanks

Comment: @Raghu, changing routes.rb as you suggested did not fix the problem, any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

My underlying problem was that a partial that was being rendered on my home page (and the one other page not displaying) was calling a field that was nil because the data in my heroku database was not as extensive as the data in my local database.